# Windows 10 doesn't boot when turning on

Tags: boot, windows-10

I recently have tried to optimize the boot up in windows 10 by setting the boot files up. Now the restarting is ok , but when I turn off the windows for some hours, then turn it on. it remains on the laptop brand name page, and won't start the windows, so I should turn it off again and turn it back on on, then it works. The windows boots almost fast, but then when the desktop is booted , I can not run a program fast, it seems that yet I should wait to be able to simply open a browser. but before optimizaing restart , it was not like this.

I really can't find the youtube video that demonstrated those damn settings. so I can not provide the information, but what I needed that time , was to roll back to the default settings, but now I have no problem , cause the issue is resolved

P.S :

As an improvement of this post, I just read this post [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/make-windows-startup-run-shutdown-faster) , I just would like to kindly imply if this is enough to optimize the boot-up , and no point is missing

on [this one](http://searchenterprisedesktop.techtarget.com/tip/Make-Windows-10-performance-sing-by-tweaking-RAM-service-settings) , I haven't created the DWORD, how does it help ?

If I could make sure how could I scroll back the windows to the previous registry condition , or redo it, cause again the restart has slowed down a bit

ps : this problem is actually resolved by an automatic windows update, without my intervention , but I still get negative votes and this is so vague

Answer (score 1):

#### Method 1-

Can you boot off of and create a linux live cd? If so, install GParted Partition Editor on the live cd and check your drive by running it. This will check for Hard Drive Corruption. Please post the GParted Screenshot if possible. Afterwards, mount the hard drive in devices and check it for missing files/corruption.

#### Method 2 -

Try Startup Repair on your computer or on the Windows Install CD (if you have it). Run startup repair to check windows for corruption. Wait for completion and try again. If it works, great! If it doesn't, try to post the log.

Comment: what if I dont have the windows cd ? and I don't , I never heard about the live cd linux , how does it work ?

Comment: If you don't have the windows cd, try method 1. A Linux Live CD is a usb drive or CD that has a linux live ISO burnt on to it. When you boot to it from BIOS, you get a Linux Operating System to run, but it will delete everything when you are done on the flash drive. In here, you start Terminal and run sudo apt-get install gparted. That will install GParted. I prefer Ubuntu as my favorite Live CD because it has the most driver support. For more info, see http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop.

Comment: Thank you so much, Since I am not familiar with this case, First, that UBUNTU is not free, should I pay for Ubuntu 15 that is now available ? and Ubuntu also accepts GParted ?

Comment: Should I follow this one : http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: I also Found this Link http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/ But it talks about Floppy Disk and CD , I am not sure it would help me , is it too old ? or a solution ?

Comment: UBCD beta (http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/ubcdlive.html) can be burnt to a USB with Universal USB Installer or LinuxLive USB Creator if you need it on USB. It also has GParted, so you won't have to install GParted. This is a Linux Live CD that will work.

Comment: Thank you very much , I opened the page , there were two links,  the "Universal USB Installer " link was not working, so I downloaded the other one , LiLi Installer, now I have to choose among so many applications that the first one is Ubuntu 15 , is it the one ? or I have to install all ?

Comment: So Far I tried to Download LiLi , but the .iso file was corrupted

Comment: I installed Linux Live Creator .exe , from there I opted download Ubuntu 15, it downloaded the .iso and at the end it said the file is correct but corrupted or altered , so I could not install it from the universtal-installer -usb.exe

Comment: Use other linux as an option.

Comment: Thank you , I installed the other Ubuntu Desktop Version , now it should be instlled , but I dont know how to run it , from All programs ? and how to find the GParted then ?

Comment: I get the Error : " wubi currently does not support Efi " !

Comment: Ok  , now I installed the Ubuntu 13.04 , the only Version that does not have this error , after many stupid negative votes I got , now what is the next step ?

Comment: Run the command from my first comment on this post to install GParted. Then run it and make sure it loads.

Comment: thank you , but my USB installation is not Bootable , so I yet can not do anything in BIOS

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix Windows 10 is to reinstall/upgrade.

1. you can download from Microsoft site Windows 10 free, use "Media Creation tool".
2. select option to create Windows 10 ISO file.
3. mount ISO file by double clicking it.
4. use Explorer (File manager) to select setup.exe on mounted ISO and execute it.
5. follow instructions on screen for reinstallation/upgrade.

This installation method allows complete rollback if you are again not happy with the new Windows installation (you can hardly get a faster Windows than a freshly installed one!!)

Comment: with this installation , how can I maintain the programs I have installed already ?

Comment: it just gives me a buy option , how can I download free

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 - look on last part of page - "Download tool now (32/64 bit)".  PROPOSED INSTALLATION IS IN PLACE UPGRADE - KEEPS USER FILES AND PROGRAMS.

Comment: @DavidPostill  well the ugrade is done periodically, but reinstall now is a huge task

Comment: @Farzad64 why are you pinging me? I'm just the editor of the post

Comment: well I am trying to improve the question